# How to create a filter formula as an arrayformula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have multiple columns that depend on this formula.

I have instances were an employee can have multiple assignments for the same Project and I use the formula to consolidate the rows and add the value that causes an extra row in the corresponding row:
[image]

I first perform a `= Unique(A3:D)` to extract the list and then:

```
=IF($A3<>"",join(", ",filter(Sheet1!E$3:E,Sheet1!$A$3:$A=$G3)),"")
```

How can I make this an ArrayFormula?
I tried it like this but the result is incorrect:

```
=arrayformula(IF($A2:A<>"",join(", ",filter(Sheet1!E$2:E,Sheet1!$A$2:$A=$G2:G)),""))
```

Here's an example spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cLXNidk6FSZbUeU0CK3XlMPWdpBMbnKMXC5gzTfMvY0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 added. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it all in one go:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY(QUERY(IF(A3:A<>"", {A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C&"♦"&D3:D, E3:E}, ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),
 "select Col1 offset 1", 0),
 IF(QUERY(QUERY(IF(A3:A<>"", {A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C&"♦"&D3:D, E3:E}, ), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "offset 1",0)<>"", 
 QUERY(QUERY(IF(A3:A<>"", {A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C&"♦"&D3:D, "♦"&E3:E&","}, ), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "limit 0",1), )})
 ,,999^99))), ", ♦", ", "), ",$", ), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

---

only column **K**:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY(QUERY(IF(A3:A<>"", {A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C&"♦"&D3:D, E3:E}, ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),
 "select Col1 offset 1", 0),
 IF(QUERY(QUERY(IF(A3:A<>"", {A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C&"♦"&D3:D, E3:E}, ), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "offset 1",0)<>"", 
 QUERY(QUERY(IF(A3:A<>"", {A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C&"♦"&D3:D, "♦"&E3:E&","}, ), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "limit 0",1), )})
 ,,999^99))), ", ♦", ", "), ",$", ), "♦")), "select Col5", 0)
```

Comment: wow. Uhm, there's no way I can learn this or try to adjust it. I honestly have no clue how this makes sense but it works so, hats off to you player0. Can I kindly ask you to point me where to modify it so that I can keep the "unique" formula? Basically, just need to replace the join and filter function in column K and leave the "unique" to do the rest because query messes up data types and leaves some columns blank in my real example.

Comment: it's the same one @player0. Or do you mean the one that contains real data? That one has around 100 columns with various formulas in between. I'd really want to keep the "unique" formula because it's so simple and only modify the K Column.

Comment: yes, the one with real data. well, the real question is that when you try this formula is the K column as it should or its not displayed correctly. if not then this formula needs to be edited first and then just trimmed for K column. if yes then we just trim it and you are good to go

Comment: Yes. The data in the K column is displayed correctly. Even in my real world example it's displayed correctly but all the other 100 columns are not, some of them have missing data because "query" formulas automatically detect data types. Yes, I would like to just trim the formula you have but I'm not sure were to begin. It all looks the same to me, you are perfoming the same set of functions 3 times and I can't wrap my head how to trim the formula for my needs.

Comment: try the 2nd fx from answer

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. You actually need all of it to get to the results in Column K whereas I thought you were trying to be nice and combine the unique formula.

Comment: the "UNIQUE" is done in QUERY via "group by Col1" here is similar stuff step-by-step: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L0XJzZbhaJXAJk8PU8mecGudp-YNsdNkuL_rdqpOX8Y/edit#gid=942322814 from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56780431/5632629