# Transpose Unique Values from Multiple Columns

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to generate unique values in `D1:F` but my formula is not working.    For example, row 1 has

```
A       B       C
milk    milk    44
```

the output should be:

```
D      E
milk   44
```

here is my formula and my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L0XJzZbhaJXAJk8PU8mecGudp-YNsdNkuL_rdqpOX8Y/edit#gid=33782449)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(unique(A1:C))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNIQUE` works only in one dimension (row or column)

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE({A:A;B:B;C:C}), "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({QUERY(QUERY(
 UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(A2:A), "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&B2:D, )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♠")), "♦")),
 "select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),
 "select Col1 offset 1",0),
 IF(QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(A2:A), "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&B2:D, )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♠")), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "offset 1",0)<>"", 
 QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(A2:A), "♠"&A2:A&"♦♀"&B2:D&",", )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♠")), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), "limit 0",1),)})
 ,,999^99))), ", ♀", ", "), ",$", ), "♀"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Okay, so then I need to transpose it someway and then take the unique values.  I created a new tab in column J and column K and gave each row an id. If you have any ideas, let me know, thanks. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L0XJzZbhaJXAJk8PU8mecGudp-YNsdNkuL_rdqpOX8Y/edit#gid=942322814

Comment: not sure what are you after with these IDs... can you explain in more detail?

Comment: The thought was that the ids allows me to run a unique function in cell M2 =UNIQUE(J2:K).  End product is to get this into an array.  I might just do this in SQL but I still need to figure out a way to get the data into format in col J and col K